# Closures and Higher-Ranked-Trait-Bounds lifetime issue

Tags: rust

I am experimenting with higher-ranked-trait bounds. In a minimal example, I created, there is a function taking a closure which takes a `&str` and returning a `&str` of the same lifetime `'a`. I explicitly declared the lifetimes on the `Fn` trait.

```
fn foo(_: &for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str) {
}

fn main() {
    foo(&|s| s);
}
```

This works fine. If I annotate the type of the parameter in the closure to be of type `&str`, I receive a lifetime error:

```
fn foo(_: &for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str) {
}

fn main() {
    foo(&|s: &str| s); // explicitly specified parameter type
}
```

That confuses me. For several reasons.

- Isn't the return type of the closure inferred to be of the same type as the
  parameter (with the same lifetime via lifetime elision)?
- The argument of `foo` is univerally quantified over all possible
  lifetimes. Why can't the type of the lifetime be arbitrary? Isn't
  `'a` just a placeholder for some lifetime?

It works without specifying the type explicitly, but why? How are those two versions different?

[playpen code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3755770b83fdfe3581b3&version=nightly)

Comment: I believe this may be [#22557](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22557): i.e. it's a bug that the compiler isn't quite connecting the dots fully.

Comment: The code compiles fine as of Rust 1.23, released Jan 4, 2018.

Answer (score 1):

At current version of Rust this compiles without warnings:

```rust
fn foo<T>(_: &T) where
T: for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> &'a str
{
}

fn main() {
    foo(&|s: &str| s); // explicitly specified parameter type
}
```